# html save image to android and ios device

Tags: html, mobile, web

I am creating a mobile website based of HTML5 and CSS3.
I am trying to find information about the following function:

Is it possible to download via a link an image from a mobile website to Android or iPhone device ?

but I didn´t find any information about.

Comment: Are you asking how to get an image on your site to automatically download when you open the image link, or are you asking how to download an image in general on android. Because the second one can be done by simply long pressing on the image and hitting `save image`...

Answer (score 0):

You shoud use download attribute:

```
<a href="image.jpg" download>Download</a>
```

You can read more on [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for useful notice. I just added the code to my post.

Comment: It will not work on iOS I'm afraid at the moment. Also not in IE nor Safari BTW. http://caniuse.com/#feat=download